# Problems installing webrtcvad via pip on arch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, webrtc, archlinux

I am trying to install [webrtcvad](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad) voice activiti detector on arch via pip but i get the following compiler error:

```
    gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/erik/anaconda3/envs/arp/compiler_compat -L/home/erik/anaconda3/envs/arp/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/erik/anaconda3/envs/arp/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/pywebrtcvad.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/vector_scaling_operations.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/spl_init.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_fractional.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_by_2_internal.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_48khz.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/real_fft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/min_max_operations.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/get_scaling_square.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/energy.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/downsample_fast.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/division_operations.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/cross_correlation.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/complex_fft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/complex_bit_reverse.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/webrtc_vad.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_sp.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_gmm.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_filterbank.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/_webrtcvad.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /home/erik/anaconda3/envs/arp/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/pywebrtcvad.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
    /home/erik/anaconda3/envs/arp/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/pywebrtcvad.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
    /home/erik/anaconda3/envs/arp/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/pywebrtcvad.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
    /home/erik/anaconda3/envs/arp/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/pywebrtcvad.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/pywebrtcvad.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/erik/anaconda3/envs/arp/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4rnipwf_/webrtcvad/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4rnipwf_/webrtcvad/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hc3rws4_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

My system information is:

```
Operating System: Antergos Linux
Kernel: Linux 5.3.12-arch1-1
Architecture: x86-64

Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
```

I tried to a [suggestion](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/issues/40#issuecomment-561576279) posted in git issues, but it didnt work for my case.
I dont know if it is relevant or not, I am also getting warnings of this type:

```
gcc -pthread -B /home/erik/anaconda3/envs/arp/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DWEBRTC_POSIX -Icbits -I/home/erik/anaconda3/envs/arp/include/python3.7m -c cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.o
In file included from cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.h:19,
                 from cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.c:11:
cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h:115:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
  115 | void WebRtcSpl_Init();
      | ^~~~
```

Any tips about how to solve the issue or where to look for additional info about the errors would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar problem appeared when I was trying to install some other software. Searching for solution I came accross [this issue](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=242682). Running the following 2 commands solved the issue for both problems:

```
sudo pacman -U https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/e/elfutils/elfutils-0.174-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz /var/cache/pacman/pkg/libelf-0.174-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
sudo pacman -U https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/b/binutils/binutils-2.30-5-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

I hope this helps anyone else. Cheers!